# Titanium Mobile Android changing order of a row

Tags: android, ios, mobile, titanium

I am a new developer when it comes to mobile applications and an iOS user myself.
For an application we have a table with 4 items, each item can be ordered form position 1 to 4 .

Now on iOS I am used to dragging the item by holding a finger down on it and change it's place. That does not seem to be the case on Android, I can not find an application on Android either which changes the position of an item.

How would you guys recommend on doing this?

Kind regards,
Vincent

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Titanium provides a property for tableView "moving" which allows tableviewRow to be re-ordered in IOS, but there is no such property for android.

I would suggest 2 solutions here

1- if your row just contains text etc. then you can listen to events "dragStart" and "dragEnd" and get the interchange the contents of rows.

2- you can splice the row and add it at specific index, but it will not give the look and feel as it feels in iPhone case.

Answer (score 1):

Titanium does not support re-arranging the rows with Android. In the case of IOS, Titanium TableView has the following properties which helps you to rearrange the tableViewRow

- [editable](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/api/Titanium.UI.TableView-property-editable)  - Determines the rows' default editable behavior, which allows them to be deleted by the user when the table is in editing or moving mode.
- [movable](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/api/Titanium.UI.TableView-property-moveable)   - Determines the rows' default moveable behavior, which allows them to be re-ordered     - Determines whether row moving mode is active.
- [moving](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/api/Titanium.UI.TableView-property-moving)
  You can use the above property properly with [dragStart](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/api/Titanium.UI.TableView-event-dragStart) and [dragEnd](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/api/Titanium.UI.TableView-event-dragEnd) events

In the case of Android, You can not do so. Please refer the following link.
[TableViewRow moveable on Android](http://developer.appcelerator.com/question/95391/tableview-moveable-on-android)